# General Gazebo Questions before starting with a master thesis (robot control strategy, joint control, physics and dynamics, gazebo-ros-components)

Tags: gazebo, physics, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi everyone!

Because I am planning to write my master thesis using Gazebo and ROS I have some basic questions concerning various topics.

The objective:
My goal is the simulation of a 5dof robot arm, its mobile plattform and some sensors (laser scanner, kinect camera etc.). Based on the existing ROS-modules of our real robot the plattform and the arm should be able to move. The simulation should be used as a hardware independent development environment for our real robot.

What do I have so far:
I got an sdf description file for the arm and its plattform. So far it looks fine. I only set the basic parameter (no physical parameters, no weights, no joint engines etc.). If I start the engine the robot arm falls to the ground observing the set collision (self collide) ranges, which I think is the expected behavior.

My Questions:
(I did some research before and maybe I overlooked something, but I just want to be sure about these things before I start the real work or maybe it becomes apparent that I made some wrong assumptions.)

1. Do I need to provide all the physical / dynamic parameter of our robot?
   We don't need a completely perfect physical behavior in the first instance. The correct     movement of the plattform and the arm would be sufficient. And I fear that we dont have all     the parameters needed in our robot documentation. Maybe it is possible to limit the dynamic     to a minimum.
2. What is the best strategy to start the development and control of all related control- /     bahavior- / ros-parts (to control the robot)?
   My plan was to work with a few sdf-files and then use a "main" gazebo-plugin for the rest. I    know that I somehow have to use diffent gazebo-plugins for sensors and ros-components   etc.. Everything needed would be called from that one plugin. Or what is the best way   respectively your recommandation?
3. How to best connect the existing ros-components / ros-logic of our real robot to the     gazebo-simulation?
   Can I call them just through the "main" gazebo-plugin like in the question before?
4. What is the best way to control the joints?
   Do I have to specify a pid-controller for every joint (problem with missing infos) or would it  be enough / the better way to control the joints through the physics::JointController Classes /     or similar?
5. What about that realtime-controller everybody is talking?
   Do I need such a controller to control my robot in a reasonable way? Wouldn't the control   just work over input for the plugins as there are ros-components for movement and grasping      which only wait for e.g. target-coordinates.

Well I think thats it for the time being.

Thank you very much for your answers once before.

Kind regards

Christoph

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2257/general-gazebo-questions-before-starting-with-a-master-thesis-(robot-control-strategy,-joint-control,-physics-and-dynamics,-gazebo-ros-components)/) by [Christoph](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/298/christoph/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 141 on 2013-04-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on 2013-04-07**:
What package is used to control the (real) arm?

**Comment by [Christoph](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/298/christoph/) on 2013-04-08**:
Hardware specific packages (`metralabs_ros`) as the interface to the real hardware and `arm_navigation` (ros stack) for calculating the arm movement itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'll try to answer each of your questions in order.

1. No, you don't need to specify all the physical properties. Gazebo will use default values in most situations.
2. A good strategy is to look at some working code. I would recommend the DRCSim package: http://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim
3. You can use ROS within a Gazebo plugin.
4. Gazebo has a built-in PID class that you can use to control joints. You can also use more sophisticated ROS controllers.
5. A real-time simulation is not mandatory to control a robot. Slower than real-time simulation just means that things more slow, your controller will be fine as long as you use simulation time.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skhan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/266/skhan/) on 2013-04-11**:
Christoph

Thanks for asking so brief question. I got the same problem.

**Comment by [skhan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/266/skhan/) on 2013-04-11**:
@nkoenig

How we can get that drcsim package? I installed drcsim using instructions and its running but how it can help us?

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-04-11**:
Look at the source code. There is a gazebo plugin called `AtlasPlugin.h` that demonstrates how to use ROS inside a  Gazebo plugin.